# Ember Data: Sideloaded records creates duplicates in Store and weird behavior

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data

Our server returns extra sideloaded records that aren't entirely related to the request, which should work, but it's causing duplicate records in the store and weird UI behavior. (http://jsfiddle.net/jgillick/agYMQ/)

To simplify it, imagine two models: child and toys. The child hasMany toys. When you add a toy to the child, the XHR responds with not only the new toy record, but also sideloads the child object and list of toys. This way more of the UI can update with one request. The JSON ends up looking like this:

```
{
    "toy": {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "doll",
        "quantity": 1
    },
    "children": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "Ben",
            "quantity": 1,
            "toys": [0, 1]
        }
    ],
    "toys": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name": "car",
            "quantity": 1
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "doll",
            "quantity": 1
        }
    ]
}
```

For some reason this causes the ember store to have 3 toys in it's record array. This shouldn't happen because these items have IDs. So loading records with duplicate IDs should cause it to overwrite the previous one. Instead, when I look at the store's record array, the records are duplicated -- IDs and all.

The other weird effect is when you add the first toy, the list item is created for it in the template, but all values are undefined. After you add the second toy the UI updates as expected. Try the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jgillick/agYMQ/

Is it really not possible to side load extra records like this? Is there a solution or am I just overlooking something?

Answer (score 0):

That's an interesting dilemma, if the same record is returned multiple times in the same response, I'm not sure if Ember should know who is the winner record (personally I'd go with the second record, but I dunno). Regardless this edge case isn't supported (not that it shouldn't be, but probably lower priority).

Regarding the other issue you're seeing I think it's running into some sort of proxy issue by manually setting the content, I'm not positive on this, but here's a more Ember way of setting this up anyway.

http://jsfiddle.net/QVqun/

```
App.IndexRoute = Em.Route.extend({
    model: function(){
        return this.store.createRecord("child", {
                'name': childName
            });
    }
});

//
// Main Program
//
App.IndexController = Em.ObjectController.extend({

    actions: {

        // Add a toy to the child
        addToy: function(){
            var self = this,
                store = this.get('store'),
                toys = this.get('model.toys'),
                toy = nextToy();

            // Create toy and add it to the child
            toy = store.createRecord('toy', {
                'name': toy.name,
                'quantity': toy.quantity
            });

            toys.pushObject(toy);
            // Save the new toy
            toy.save();
        }
    },

    storeToys: function(){
        return this.store.all('toy');
    }.property(),

    storeToysLen: Em.computed.alias('storeToys.length')

});
```